# Google Apps Script Execution Under Owner's Email

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I have access to a specific Google Sheets document as an editor, but I'm not the owner of the sheet. However, I can edit the code of the associated Google Apps Script. When I run the script, it executes under my email address. What steps should I take to ensure that the Google Apps Script operates under the owner's email address?

I want the script to send emails using the owner's email address as the sender. How can I make sure that when I run the script, it always runs under the owner's email, not mine? Any guidance on code modifications, authorization, and execution practices is highly appreciated. Thank you!

I tried to run the code with owner email but it's not working

Comment: `tried to run the code with owner email but it's not working` Explain "not working"